Error in finding work done by a spring
Suppose one end of a spring is attached to wall and the other end is attached to a block. Consider the wall on left and the block on right side of the spring. By application of an external force, the block is moved x units towards right. After that the external force stops. Thereafter, spring applies spring force to move the block back to the equilibrium position. Let the spring constant be K. So force applied by spring initially will be $kx$ . After block moves $dx$ distance towards left, such that it is at distance $x_1$ from equilibrium the foce applied will be $kx_1$ . And work done initially will be $|f||dx|cos \theta$ . Which will be equal to $kxdx$ since $\theta$ is 0 . After that work done will be $kx_1dx$.  So we can say that total work done will be $\int_x^0kxdx$ = $ \frac k2 [x^2]_x^0$ = $-\frac k2 x^2$ . But if displacement of the block is in the direction of force applied by the spring, how can the work be negative? . Moreover all $kxdx$ are postive, so how will there sum be negative? Or have I made an error?

where did $\theta$ come from?

Since there seems to be some confusion about the sign I am expanding my old answer.
Value of work done is given by $\vec{F} \cdot \vec{dx}$.
$$\int_0^WdW=\int_a^bFdx\cos\theta$$ What this statement means is:
If a force $\vec{F}$ moves a body along x axis from initial position $a$ to final position $b$, the above is the work done. Displacement $dx$ has to be along positive x axis as the $x$ in magnitude of force $F=kx$, (WHOSE ELEMENT is $dx$) is along positive x axis(or else the magnitude of force would not have increased as we move along positive x).
Since we are considering $dx$ to be along the positive x axis,$\cos {\theta}$ is $-1$ as $\theta$ (the angle between force vector and displacement vector) is $\pi$, intial position $a=A$ and final position $b=0$.
So $$\int_a^bFdx\cos\theta=\int_A^0kxdx\cos\pi=\int_A^0-kxdx$$$$=\frac12 kA^2$$

you're partially correct, the $-$ sign would be cancelled as the $x$ (displacement) is also negative.

@AmitVerma no, work done by the spring is calculated assuming positive displacement and then the limits are set from x to 0 which causes it to be negative.

so do you mean that the work done would be positive?

Even if the value of force acting is $-kx$ , won't the $||$ modulus function make it positive?

The sign of $x$ shouldn't matter, since it's $-\frac 1 2 x^2|_x^0=--x^2 = +x^2 \ge 0$.

@JEB What i am trying to say is that even if value of force acting will be $-kx$, due to modulus function won't the integral be $\int_x^0 kxdx$ only?

@MohitMishra what modulus function are you talking about?

@AltercatingCurrent I am talking about the modulus in the formula of work, i.e. W = $|f||s|cos \theta$

@MohitMishra Work done is $F \cdot dx$. If we consider $dx$ to be along the positive x axis, then $\cos {\theta}$ is $-1$ as $\theta=\pi$. Now, the limits are from $x$ to $0$ which causes the final result to be positive.

@MohitMishra Do check my edited improved answer

@AmitVerma Do check my edited improved answer

There is no theta in one dimension as a vector dot product, but if you are going to insist there is, it has two allowed values: $\cos\theta=\pm 1$. It may simpler to just use $dW = F dx$ with signed $F$ and $x$ according to $F = -kx$. btw: the guaranteed component-free dot product in any dimensions over ${\mathbb R}$ or ${\mathbb C}$ is $\langle a| b\rangle = \frac 1 4[|a+b|^2 - |a-b|^2]$

@AltercatingCurrent I got it now, thanks


But if displacement of the block is in the direction of force applied
by the spring, how can the work be negative?

I found it difficult following your post, but the following addresses the type of work done by the spring and the external force that moved the block to the right.
Initially, when the external force moves the block to the right, the external force does positive work since the direction of that force is the same as the direction of the displacement of the block. This results in energy transferred to the spring/block system. At the same time the spring does negative work since its restoring force is opposite to the direction of the displacement of the block, taking the energy given it by the external force and storing it as elastic potential energy.
When the block moves to the left you didn't say whether or not the external force was still present. In any case, when the block moves to the left the spring does positive work, since now its restoring force is in the same direction as the displacement of the block, losing elastic potential energy and giving kinetic energy to the block. The result will be oscillation of the block where energy is converted between elastic potential energy and kinetic energy, ultimately stopping due to energy loss in the form of heat (applicable to all real springs).
Hope this helps.

You say, "when the block moves to the left the spring does positive work". I am also saying that spring will do postive work since force is in the same direction as displacement of block. But the integration is giving negative result. That was my confusion.

@MohitMishra as has already been pointed out the sign of the integrand is incorrect

Students often get in a tangle because they do not specify the system they are working with.
In this example the system could be the spring with an external force acting on it due to the block $\vec F_{\rm sb}$ or it could be the block with an external force acting on it due to the spring $\vec F_{\rm bs}$ with $\vec F_{\rm sb}=-\vec F_{\rm bs}$ (N3L).
The next thing to note is that the work done by a force $\vec F$ undergoing a displacement along the x-axis is
$\displaystyle \int_{x_{\rm initial}}^{x_{\rm final}}\vec F \cdot d\vec x = \int_{x_{\rm initial}}^{x_{\rm final}}F\,\hat x \cdot dx \hat x =  \int_{x_{\rm initial}}^{x_{\rm final}}F\, dx$
where $F$ is the component of force $\vec F$in the $\hat x$ direction and the sign of $dx$ is determined by the limits of integration.

System - spring
Work done by external force on spring is
$\displaystyle \int_x^0\vec F_{\rm sb} \cdot d\vec x = \int_x^0k\,x\,\hat x \cdot dx\,\hat x = \int_x^0 k\,x\,dx = -\frac 12 kx^2.$
System - block
Work done by external force on block is
$\displaystyle \int_x^0\vec F_{\rm bs} \cdot d\vec x = \int_x^0k\,x\,(-\hat x) \cdot dx\,\hat x = -\int_x^0 k\,x\,dx = +\frac 12 kx^2.$

Usual question: why -1?
